# DartEditor.exe and java exit code 1

Tags: eclipse, dart

I try to run DartEditor on Windows. I've downloaded the latest version from:
dartlang.org/docs/getting-started/editor/index-win.html

(i tried both the stable and untested latest version - same results)

At first Editor was facing problem with finding the java virtual machine, so I added the path to the "DartEditor.ini", which now looks like that:

```
-data
workspace
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\bin\javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms40m
-Xmx1024m
```

Now java is starting BUT it's returning following error:
(sorry for URLs, but i'm not yet allowed to post images)

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCgwf.png]

and information:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKSC3.png]

I suppose that this error is connected with eclipse, but sadly I have no idea where exactly the problem is. Any help appreciated.

Comment: What version of windows are you using

Comment: OK, what has worked for me is just simply removing the "DartEditor.ini"! This is quite strange, but now editor is running :)

I hope, this is going to help sbd.

Comment: Great that you found a solution ;), you should be able to answer your own question in a day.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see anything wrong with your posted .ini contents, it could be that you are seeing https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=188968

Essentially the -Xmx1024m might be too large and the jvm can't find a contiguous block of memory that large.  Shared libraries might be loaded in the middle of the address space fragmentin the available memory).

By removing the .ini file, you get the default Xmx args which are much lower.  You could try changing to -Xmx512m or -Xmx768m.

Comment: I was having the same problem starting DartEditor.exe.  I changed the Xmx... arg to 512m and the program started as expected.  +1

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue until I upgraded my JRE from version 6 to 7.  Though dartlang.org states that Dart Editor's minimum required Java version is 6, I believe they may have forgotten to update this info.

Additionally, dartlang.org states that Windows XP is not supported. FYI

Comment: Upgrading my machine to JRE 7 fixed this issue for me.